# Database Updating Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Trying to simple update operation but error is showing.

**Error message**

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

**Code**

```
 TBL_WORKINFO updateData = new TBL_WORKINFO();
                updateData = context.TBL_WORKINFO.Where(x => x.Id == inputEmployeeID).FirstOrDefault();
                updateData.Snot = "1";
                updateData.Sone = Sone.ToString();
                updateData.Stwo = Stwo.ToString();
                updateData.Sthree = Sthree.ToString();
                updateData.Sfour = Sfour.ToString();
                updateData.Sfive = Sfive.ToString();
                updateData.Yone = Yone.ToString();
                updateData.Ytwo = Ytwo.ToString();
                updateData.Uregistration = uRegistration.ToString();
                updateData.Flag = "1";
                updateData.Rprime = RPrime.ToString();
                updateData.VotingcontentM = "1";
                context.SaveChanges();
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Maybe your second line does not return a entity and you are setting the remaining properties, but upon save the primary key is not set...

Comment: @PeterSchneider updateData would be null if there is no data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException

Exception thrown by DbContext when the saving of changes to the database fails. Note that state entries referenced by this exception are not serialized due to security and accesses to the state entries after serialization will return null.

1. Check your fields names.
2. Update your entity mapping.

Maybe you have inner exception with more details, when write his.